# "Right" REST URL to get all resources within all resources?

Tags: rest

So... I am aware that this question could be dangerously close to being *opinion based* . I'm hoping is not, and that the REST standard is clear about what I'm going to ask but if it's not, I'll close it.

I have a website (in Django, with the data being stored in Postgres) with `Product`(-s) and `Category`(-ies) Each `category` can contain several `product`(-s).

So, the question is: What would be the "right" endpoint (if there's any) to GET all the categories with all the products in each?

I believe it would be clear getting all the products of a specific category. For instance, if the category ID was `24`, in order to get all its products, I would write:

`http://myserver.com/api/categories/24/products`

But how about ALL the categories with ALL the products in each?

Would it be `http://myserver.com/api/categories/products`?

Would it be `http://myserver.com/api/categories/all/products`?

Would it be better using some kind of parameter, such as `http://myserver.com/api/categories?mode=all_products` ?

The idea would be having a response like this (JSON format)

```
{
    "25": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 1 in category 25",
        "price": 100
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product 2 in category 25",
        "price": 200
    }],
    "26": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product 1 in category 26",
        "price": 300
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Product 2 in category 26",
        "price": 400
    }]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It could be just http://myserver.com/api/products. Due to the URL meaning is full set of the available products and doesn't matter the result's format considers categories. E.g.: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @4xy :-) The thing with that particular URL is that I already have it to get a list of all the products regardless of (or not sorted by, rather) its categories.

Comment: `REST standard`? REST is just an architectural style, NOT a standard! Next, REST doesn't care much about your URI design, just that you respect the backing protocol (HTTP in your case) and that URIs are what they claim to be - unique. Something like http://someserver.com/foo/bar/adjfajdöaj/sajdkaj is just as RESTful as one of your presented URIs (good or bad is opinion-based)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as REST is concerned if you are uniquely representing the resource in the url so that it is `cacheable` (and abiding with HATEOAS but let's skip that part), it doesn't really matter how you structure your urls. With that said in my opinion, since you want to get all the products, your url should be something like

```
GET /products         # to return all products with their associated categories
GET /category/24/products  # to return all products belonging to a particular category
```

Note:- Although url structure is not exactly a part of REST, but designing url in terms of an entity/resource and an identifier does makes it easier to create RESTful APIs. Well structured urls also makes them easier to be consumed by clients.

Comment: While for a human a well-structured URI might be easier to interpret, not all clients will be able to do so. One might argue that specifying a pregnant naming-scheme for resources might interfer with [rules given by Roy Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) as this may lead to implementors to rely on these paths and therefore tightly-coupling their client to the API instead of using URIs & relations found in the response.

Comment: I meant it makes it easier for developers who develop the clients that interact with api. Secondly if someone is going to hardcode urls, url being readable or not doesn't matter. There is nothing wrong in following a convention and principle of least surprise

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for... A _sensible_ URL schema...I know that they are just URLs, and as such, I could use whatever I felt like... I just wanted some advice on how to make "reasonable" URLs. Thank you :)

Comment: The second example should be `/categories/{categoryId}/products` cause you are first filtering from categories and then returning its products.